# Can I quit cl-sdl2:with-event-loop () with a user-defined event?

Tags: common-lisp, sdl-2

I need to send a quit signal to one of several instances of sdl-applications. If I do (sdl2:push-event :quit) or (sdl2:push-quit-event) it goes to any/all of the applications, I need it to go to only one.

So I tried registering a user-defined event with an integer as data, but cannot get it to quit the event loop like :quit does. Is that possible?

Here is a little test program showing what I am trying to do. Doing (sdl2:push-event :quit) twice terminates the program, but trying it with :my-quit only prints the data value, but does not quit the loop.

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload :bordeaux-threads)
  (ql:quickload :sdl2))

(defparameter *display* 0)

(defun sdl1 ()
  (sdl2:with-init (:video)
    (sdl2:hide-cursor)
    (sdl2:with-window (win
                       :x (sdl2:windowpos-centered *display*)
                       :y (sdl2:windowpos-centered *display*)
                       :flags '())
      (sdl2:with-renderer (ren win)
        (dotimes (n 2)
          (sdl2:with-event-loop (:method :poll)
            (:idle ()
                   (sdl2:set-render-draw-color ren (* n 50) (* n 50) (* n 50) 255)
                   (sdl2:render-clear ren)
                   (sdl2:render-present ren)
                   (sleep 2))
            (:my-quit (:user-data data)
                         (pprint data)
                         t)
            (:quit () t)))))))

(defun sdltest (d)
  (setf *display* d)
  (sdl2:register-user-event-type :my-quit)
  (bt:make-thread (lambda () (sdl2:make-this-thread-main #'sdl1)))
  (sleep 1)
  (sdl2:push-user-event :my-quit 0))
```

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using sdl2:with-event-loop altogether, but then sdl2:hide-cursor does not work.